# Test hypothesis of a given problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference

Hi guys I found this problem in an old book but can't seem to find a solution to it. To be honest I don't really have much of an idea how to go about it. I am trying to study statistics on my own. Can anyone give me an answer or at least some useful directions?

> You are looking at 3 regions in England and would like to analyse differences between the regions in the monthly salary. In doing so, you are interested in whether the average salaries in
> are different in the regions.

Which test procedure can I use to test the hypothesis of the above question? In the following, assume that the test calculated is significant. Now I want to know whether the salaries differ from each other in pairs.

Comment: (1) Could you include more details about the format of the data? How many salaries (observations) do you have for each region?  (2) You should always start by properly defining what's the hypothesis of your test. (3) "[...] assume that the test calculated is significant" - this does't make sense. If you already knew that the test was significant, you'd already have your answer.

Comment: @AdriàLuz (1)in the book isn't stated how many saleries there are about each region because it directly says do focus on the avrerage saleries (2) the hypothesis isnt given and i should find it myself but i cant figure it out (3) as i stated before the book firstly tells you to find a test procedure and than if you cant gives you already that the test sagnificant is

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define some terms:
$$
\mu: \text{overall mean}\\
\mu_i: \text{mean for region } i, \space i\in \{1,2,3\}\\
\tau_i = \mu_i-\mu
$$

You're interested in understanding whether there are differences in average monthly salary between the three regions. Therefore, you're hypotheses are:
$$
H_0: \tau_1=\tau_2=\tau_3=0\\
H_1: \tau_i\neq0 \text{ at least for one }i
$$

You can test this hypothesis by carrying out an analysis of variance (ANOVA). In R:

```r
# simulate some data
set.seed(1)
regions <- tibble(
  region = c(rep('north', 10), rep('south', 10), 
             rep('east', 10)),
  salary = c(rnorm(10, 19000, 2000), rnorm(10, 20000, 1000), 
             rnorm(10, 24000, 2000))
)

sample_n(regions, 5)
```

*Output:*

```r
region  salary
<chr>   <dbl>
south   20821.22            
north   18389.22            
north   17359.06            
east    20021.30            
south   17785.30
```

```r
# carry out an ANOVA
aov_regions <- aov(salary ~ region, regions)
summary(aov_regions)
```

*Output:*

```r
            Df    Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
region       2 148320705 74160353   25.05 7.04e-07 ***
Residuals   27  79923237  2960120                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In this case, we reject $H_0$ at the 0.1% significance level and therefore conclude that there are differences in average salary between the three regions (note we already knew that because we simulated the data that way).

For completeness' sake, imagine that the three regions didn't have different salaries:

```r
# simulate some data
set.seed(1)
regions_equal <- tibble(
  region = c(rep('north', 10), rep('south', 10), rep('east', 10)),
  salary = rnorm(30, 20000, 2000)
)

sample_n(regions_equal, 5)
```

*Output:*

```r
region  salary
<chr>   <dbl>
south   21642.44            
north   19389.22            
north   18359.06            
east    16021.30            
south   15570.60
```

```r
# carry out an ANOVA
aov_regions_equal <- aov(salary ~ region, regions_equal)
summary(aov_regions_equal)
```

*Output:*

```r
            Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
region       2  3074875 1537438   0.432  0.653
Residuals   27 95989044 3555150               
---
```

Now the p-value is $0.653\gg 0.05$ so we couldn't reject the null hypothesis of equal salaries in this case.