# Hypothesis test to election problem

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, contingency-tables

Hi guys I found this problem in an old book but cant to find a solution to it. To be honest I dont really have much of an idea how to go about it because I am trying to study statistics on my own. Can anyone help me please?

In the context of the Bundestag election, you would like to check whether the neighbourhood within Munich
could have an influence on the decision to vote. To do this, you compare the election results of
four selected electoral districts in the 2017 Bundestag election. The parties were able to achieve the following second vote results at that time:

[image]

Which test would you use to test the hypothesis? Also state the hypothesis pair for this test. Then perform this test at significance level $α = 0.05$ in R. Which test decision
do you arrive at?

A friend told me "This looks like a good candidate for χ2 test for independence." but I can't figure out how to use this information

Comment: Are you the same person as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546129/calculate-bayesian-point-estimator-and-the-likelihood-estimator? or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/546130/test-hypothesis-of-a-given-problem? All questions start the same...

Comment: @Pitouille no I just watched how they started the question and used it myself. As I am trying to learn as much as possible

Comment: ok... I just thought that there was an issue with the accounts... But if you found it in a new book, it is also good ;-)

Comment: @Pitouille yeah it is a book about R. Do you have any ideas about the problem

Comment: I believe you need to convert your table in a more "english" style since it might be challenging for non german speaker to understand the headers.

Comment: In other words, you are interested in testing whether the distribution of parties is different between the districts?

Comment: @user2974951 yeah basically whether living in a drisctrict influences who you vote

Comment: Hint: it starts with chi and ends with square.

Comment: "the distribution of parties is different between the districts" and "whether living in a district influences who you vote" are very different questions